# How to select a single check box among multiple boxes based on the label text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, checkbox, label

Hi I am trying to automate a scenario where a search is initiated using City name and that would give me the list of available test centers in the city with check boxes to choose required test center. I have tried many ways but failed to select a Test center based on the 'Post code' available in label text.

There are 2 test centers(testCenter_1 and testCenter_2) as shown in below code, and each test center has a check box and its address is displayed in label tag. I am trying to locate and select Test center 2 based on its post code (HP19 8GJ) in label tag.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
                <div id="testCenterList">
                    <div style="visibility:hidden;">
                    </div>
     <table cellspacing="0" id="centerTable">
       <caption class="access">This table lists the test centres closest to the area that searched      </caption>         
                        <thead>…</thead>
                        <tbody id="testCenterListTable">
                            <tr id="testCenter_1" class="group0">
                                    <td class="selectRow  displayDesktopOnlyView" scope="row">
<input id="selectedTestCenters:1" type="checkbox" name="selectedTestCenters" value="48958">
<label for="selectedTestCenters:1" class="access">&nbsp;Pearson Centre - 9 Lloyds Street Northampton NN1 2NP</label>                                        
                                    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="testCenter_2" class="group0">
                                    <td class="selectRow  displayDesktopOnlyView" scope="row">
<input id="selectedTestCenters:2" type="checkbox" name="selectedTestCenters" value="79312">
<label for="selectedTestCenters:2" class="access">&nbsp;Pearson Centre - 5 Smeaton Close Aylesbury HP19 8GJ</label>
                                    </td>
                                <td>
</tr>
```

[Please click here to see the screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTNRB.png)

I could select testCenter_2 using xpath and id as shown below, but couldn't come up with a common locator to identify one test center based on their label text.
Note: I have used element visibility condition here as the search results appear in bottom of the page.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*@id='selectedTestCenters:2']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='selectedTestCenters:2']")).click();
```

To locate the test center 2 based on label text and select the check box, I have used below line but it gives me ElementNotInteractableException.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='testCenterListTable']/tr[2]/td/label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]")).click();
```

Suggestions please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put html code as a text so that we can test it. Do not use images.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyR. and DebanjanB, I appreciate your advice about the code. When I copy the element or outer html, it returns more than 1000 lines.Hence I've removed the content within the tags of all test centers except for one. Please let me know if the code included in the question looks fine?

Comment: In the html code is no select or checkbox. Can you pls elaborate what exactly is your problem? Add your code, expected behaviour and current behaviour/exception.

Comment: Thanks @pburgr for looking into this. I have now updated the question and code for more clarity. Please have a look and let me know if it is still missing any details.

Comment: 1. make sure element with id 'selectedTestCenters:2' is clickable when proceeding manualy 2. use 'elementToBeClickable' instead of 'visibilityOfElementLocated', there can be few miliseconds difference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I was trying to click wrong element as you pointed out. As @E.Wiest suggested, navigating to label text and then targeting the previous clickable element (input) by using 'preceding' did the trick. Could you answer my question that I asked E.Wiest in the comments to his answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested @pburgr, using `elementToBeClickable` condition is one of the option. Also, it's probably better if you target the `input` element, not the `label`. You could fix your XPath accordingly :

```
//label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]/preceding::input[1]
```

If the previous option doesn't work, use JSE to click on the element :

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]/preceding::input[1]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

**EDIT** :

If you want to search inside all test centers you can use one the following XPath (using `//` or `[*]` to inspect every `tr` elements) :

```
//*[@id='testCenterListTable']//tr/td/label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]/preceding::input[1]

//*[@id='testCenterListTable']/tr[*]/td/label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]/preceding::input[1]
```

Comment: Excellent!!This worked for me. Thanks much @E.Wiest. Earlier I tried to click the box by locating the input tag, but it failed because the text is in label. I have never come across with preceding' option before. However my problem is only half solved. Post code doesn't always appear in the same position it may appear first in the list or 5th. So can I use any alternate option to look at all test centers with given text instead of targeting second test center(tr[2]) directly in this line? `xpath("//*[@id='testCenterListTable']/tr[2]/td/label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]/preceding::input[1]")`

Comment: Sure. If you want to search inside all test centers you can use one the following XPath (using `//` or `[*]` to inspect every `tr` elements) : `//*[@id='testCenterListTable']//tr/td/label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]/preceding::input[1]` or `//*[@id='testCenterListTable']/tr[*]/td/label[contains(text(),'HP19 8GJ')]/preceding::input[1]`.

Comment: Perfect! This is what I am looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Comment has been added to my original post. Feel free to mark it as accepted if your problem is solved.